# allow everyone(public) to create event in google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am designing web application for society management,
where i am trying to give event creation functionality through google calendar.
Other members are not able to create event in the calendar. I searched a lot but I am getting only one solution i.e. to invite
through gmail or to manually add gmail accounts and give permission. But i want make this calendar public everyone can
create event through it. Is this possible? if yes How?

Comment: please answer this question if any one has idea about it

Comment: use google calendar API with a Service Account. Build a web-based GUI where people can add events (make sure it cannot be attacked by spammers adding endless junk to your calendar). Users submit the event data via a form, and your backend submits the data to the Google Calendar through the API, authenticating using a Service Account so that no directly login to Google Calendar is needed by the user. It's not possible to add events to a calendar without some sort of permission (probably due to the risk of spam).

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?